# My Code failed with error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'"

Tags: python

I have this pieces of code that crawled a site, extract all the needed url from the site, format the url into required format, then at a point where i am suppose to add it to a set for further proccessing. I encounter the following error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'"
The part of the code is as follow

```
class Finder(bs4.BeautifulSoup):

   def __init__(self, m, page_url):
      super().__init__(m, 'html.parser')
      self.page_url = page_url
      self.pdf_url_links = set()

  def handle_starttag(self, name, namespace, nsprefix, attrs):

    if name == 'a':
        for (attributes, value) in attrs.items():
            if ('.pdf&') not in value: pass
            else:
                list_of_links = search_queue_url(value)
                print(list_of_links)
```

I got the following url on my screen when I print the variable 'list_of_links' above:

```
https://julianoliver.com/share/free-science-books/basic_math_and_algebra.pdf
https://www.math.ksu.edu/~dbski/writings/further.pdf
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf
http://www.textbooksonline.tn.nic.in/Books/Std10/Std10-Maths-EM-1.pdf
http://www.corestandards.org/wp-content/uploads/Math_Standards.pdf
https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/gre_math_review.pdf
https://www.math.ust.hk/~machas/differential-equations.pdf
```

However, when I attempt to add each of the above url to my set with below code,

```
self.pdf_url_links.add(list_of_links)
```

I got the following error bellow,

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Projects\BookScapie\BookScrapie\BookScrapie\link_finders.py", line 7, in __init__
super().__init__(m, 'html.parser')
 File "C:\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 228, in __init__
self._feed()
 File "C:\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 289, in _feed
self.builder.feed(self.markup)
 File "C:\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 167, in feed
parser.feed(markup)
 File "C:\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\html\parser.py", line 111, in feed
self.goahead(0)
 File "C:\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\html\parser.py", line 171, in goahead
k = self.parse_starttag(i)
 File "C:\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\html\parser.py", line 345, in parse_starttag
self.handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
 File "C:\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 65, in handle_starttag
self.soup.handle_starttag(name, None, None, attr_dict)
 File "C:\Projects\BookScapie\BookScrapie\BookScrapie\link_finders.py", line 22, in handle_starttag
self.pdf_url_links.add(list_of_links)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'

I will appreciate any good ideas on what I am doing right.
I am using python 3.5

Comment: Any chance you have redefined `set`

Comment: @AChampion, No, I haven't redefined the set anywhere.

Comment: Apparently, `self.pdf_url_links` is None. But that is not caused by any code we see here.

Comment: @zvone, that is a great concerns to me as well, because when I print "self.pdf_url_links shortly before adding it to the initial declared set, I got the list of the above url

Comment: Your traceback starts with `super().__init__(m, 'html.parser')` and that is not in the code, so it is impossible to know what happened.

Comment: @zvone I added it to make the question answerable (obviously it is called in the constructor before the attribute is initialized).

Comment: You call super's `__init__` and it ends up using `self.pdf_url_links`, which is not yet initialized. So, set `self.pdf_url_links` first and call `super` after that.

Comment: @zvone, Thanks for the last observation, your last suggestion is my saving grace. I will like to accept your suggestion as my solution/answer but it seem there is no way to do that in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the way BeautifulSoup constructor works.

```
class Finder(bs4.BeautifulSoup):

   def __init__(self, m, page_url):
      super().__init__(m, 'html.parser')
      self.page_url = page_url
      self.pdf_url_links = set()
```

As soon as `BeautifulSoup.__init__` is called, the parsing begins, which eventually calls `handle_starttag` method.

Here, the overridden version of `handle_starttag` tried to access `self.pdf_url_links`, which was not initialized.

The solution is to initialize everything that is needed for parsing before calling the super constructor:

```
   def __init__(self, m, page_url):
      self.page_url = page_url
      self.pdf_url_links = set()
      super().__init__(m, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not inherit from `BeautifulSoup`; rather, use aggregation and its query interface instead! The `BeautifulSoup.__init__` will call your overridden `handle_starttag`, before `self.pdf_url_links` is initialized.

The `BeautifulSoup` class has a `__getattr__` implementation that does [sub-tag navigation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names), returning `None` if no match found; in this case, there is no `<pdf_url_links>` tag in the soup, so `self.pdf_url_links` returns `None`.

---

Instead try something like

```
def find_links(m):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(m, 'html.parser')
    links = set()
    for a in soup.find_all('a'):
        href = a.get('href')
        if href and '.pdf&' in href:
            links.add(href)

    return links
```

Comment: This your implementation equally work for me, however because of peculiar needs, my previous implementation is now working after I followed the suggestion by @zvone above. I just moved my new attribute above `supper()__init__`. Thanks